# Best practice for app engine transactions involving purchase of a unique item?

Tags: google-app-engine, transactions, idempotent

**Nevermind:** The problem was on the client side, apparently google chrome is more aggressive than I expected with caching the results of get requests. Testing with firefox yields the expected results. I'm going to vote for the deletion of this question.

I have 2 models, User and Item. User has a 'credits' property that indicates how much money the user has. Item has an 'owner' property that is 'None' if it is not owned, and the id of a User if it is owned. I am attempting to put the following steps into a transaction:

1. Get the user by id (not an ancestor query)
2. Get the item by id (not an ancestor query)
3. Abort if the item is already owned.
4. Abort if the user does not have enough credits.
5. Reduce the user's credits by the item's price.
6. Set the 'owner' property of item to the user's id.

If everything goes okay, I indicate to the client that their purchase went through, outside of the @ndb.transactional decorated function.

To test, I hammer this function rapidly (to simulate rapidly pressing the buy button). In response, I get several indications that my purchase went through, but I expect only one such indication. My expectation is that the first transaction will go through, and the others will fail at step 3. If they do not fail at step three, then I assume that they started together, but only one transaction will pass the test at the end of the transaction that checks the update time, and throw an exception. Both of my assumptions appear to be false.

Notably, my transactions "work" in the sense that I do not overspend credits. I just tell the client several times that they have made the same purchase because I get no exceptions.

Also, the abort on step three does start triggering after a short delay, but not soon enough to catch the initial spamming.

```
class BuyItem(webapp2.RequestHandler):

    @ndb.transactional(xg=True)
    def buyItemTransaction(self, user_id, item_id):
        user = User.get_by_id(user_id)
        item = Item.get_by_id(item_id)
        if item.owner_id is not None:
            return dict(result='error', message='Item already owned.')
        if user.credits < 5000:
            return dict(result='error', message='Not enough credits.')
        user.credits -= 5000
        user.put()
        item.owner_id = user_id
        item.put()
        return dict(result='success', message='You bought the item.') 

    def get(self):
        user_id = users.get_current_user().user_id()
        item_id = self.request.get('item_id')
        try:
            response = self.buyItemTransaction(user_id, item_id)
        catch TransactionFailedError, e:
            # Transaction went through previously, so send no response.
            return
        self.response.out.write(json.dumps(response))
```

What is my misconception?

Comment: Does your item have a parent ? 
Is is xg-transactions ?

Comment: @JimmyKane No, no parents, and yes, I am using cross-group transactions.

Comment: A bit of code would help. Just an example

Comment: Still trying to help. What if you use db.transactions not ndb.transactions?

Comment: The result is identical (I was originally using db). I think you're right in your answer, I just need a way to prevent the double posting. Any idea?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21648/discussion-between-jimmykane-and-shino)

Answer (score 1):

Your implementation is ok as I see it.

Your problem:

> To test, I hammer this function rapidly (to simulate rapidly pressing
>   the buy button). In response, I get several indications that my
>   purchase went through, but I expect only one such indication.

So imagine that you where not using transactions, and just hit the button after the purchase has been made.

Shouldn't it always fail on step 3? Is it?

So your problem is not the transactions. That should be ok. Your problems is in the checks against step 3 etc

**EDIT**

> Multiple processes varying for the opportunity to write to an entity
>   group at the same time is known as contention. Two processes are
>   contending for the write; the first to commit wins

In other words your 2nd (concurrent transaction) might be logging messages but it's actual read/writes are not applied if the fist transaction succeds

The latest code that you added should be checked before double posting the same message.

This might help:

> The datastore uses entity groups to determine what happens when two
>   processes attempt to update data in the entity group at the same time.
>   When this happens, the first update that completes “wins,” and the
>   other update is canceled. App Engine notifies the process whose update
>   is canceled by raising an exception. In most cases, the process can
>   just try the update again and succeed. But the app must decide for
>   itself how to go about retrying, since important data may have changed
>   between attempts. This style of managing concurrent access is known as
>   optimistic concurrency control. It’s “optimistic” in the sense that
>   the database tries to perform the operations without checking whether
>   another process is working with the same data (such as with a
>   “locking” mechanism), and only checks for collisions at the end,
>   optimistic that the operations will succeed. The update is not
>   guaranteed to succeed, and the app must re-attempt the operations or
>   take some other course of action if the data changes during the
>   update.

Also try to handle exceptions:

```
  try:
      response = self.buyItemTransaction(user_id, item_id)
  except TransactionFailedError, e:
      # Report an error to the user.
```

Comment: Could you elaborate a little? I'm not quite following.

Comment: Are you checks on step 3 ok ? See updated answer.

Comment: Oh, I see, thanks for elaborating. Yes, they appear to be okay because they eventually start working. That is, after my initial spamming, the abort on step 3 begins to work. There's just a delay. That was not clear in my question; I'll update it.

Comment: Se also another edit @shino

Comment: Ah, interesting. I was expecting an exception to be thrown in that case, and that my messages would not be sent. This is incorrect?

Comment: @shino try to catch the exeption

Comment: That's the thing-- I was expecting to prevent the double posting by catching an exception, but I never get an exception.